# I have created a left navigation pane using html. when I click on particular page, color need to be changed for entire block. But it's changing only

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, navigation

I have created a left navigation pane using html. when I click on particular page, colour need to be changed for that particular block. But colour is changing only for the text. Hover is happening correctly, but active is showing only for text with  box over it. How can I change the colour for that particular block when clicked?

```js
$('#wrapper').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents('#wrapper').find('.active').removeClass('active').end().end().addClass('active');
    $(activeTab).show();
  });
```

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 178px;
  position: fixed;
  background: #377ba1;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding: 0px, 0px;
  /* margin-top: 0px; */
}

.wrapper  ul li{
  padding: 33px;
  box-align: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bdb8d7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.05);
}    

.wrapper  ul li a{
  color: #bdb8d7;
  display: block;
}
.wrapper  ul li a .fas{
  width: 60px;

  
}
.wrapper ul li a.active
{
     background-color:#0f5f8d;
     /* padding: 5px; */
     /* font-size: 11px; */
     /* margin-left: 20px; */
     /* height: 50px; */
}

.wrapper  ul li:hover{
  background-color: #0f5f8d;
}
.wrapper li a:hover:not(.active) 
{
    background-color:#0f5f8d;
}
    
.wrapper ul li:hover a{
  color: #fff;
}

    
.wrapper .main_content{
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 200px;
}

.wrapper .main_content .header{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 23px;
  background:#377ba1;
  color: #717171;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e4e8;
}

.wrapper .main_content .info{
  margin: 20px;
  color: #717171;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.wrapper .main_content .info div{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
         <ul>
            <li><a class= "active" href="#" ><i class="fas"></i>Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fas"></i>Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fas"></i>About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fas"></i>Blogs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fas"></i>Contacts</a></li>
            
        </ul>  
  </div>
```

Comment: Where is `activeTab` defined in `$(activeTab).show();`

Comment: Also it should be `.wrapper` and not `#wrapper`

Comment: There is div class =wrapper, Can it be used ?

Comment: Yes, look at my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

First it should be `.wrapper` and not `#wrapper` since there is no element with id the `wrapper`

```
$('.wrapper').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.wrapper .active').removeClass('active')
  $(this).addClass('active');
  //$(activeTab).show();
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$('.wrapper').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.wrapper .active').removeClass('active')
  $(this).addClass('active');
  //$(activeTab).show();
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 178px;
  position: fixed;
  background: #377ba1;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding: 0px, 0px;
  /* margin-top: 0px; */
}

.wrapper ul li {
  padding: 33px;
  box-align: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bdb8d7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
}

.wrapper ul li a {
  color: #bdb8d7;
  display: block;
}

.wrapper ul li a .fas {
  width: 60px;
}

.wrapper ul li a.active {
  background-color: #0f5f8d;
  /* padding: 5px; */
  /* font-size: 11px; */
  /* margin-left: 20px; */
  /* height: 50px; */
}

.wrapper ul li:hover {
  background-color: #0f5f8d;
}

.wrapper li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #0f5f8d;
}

.wrapper ul li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}

.wrapper .main_content {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 200px;
}

.wrapper .main_content .header {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 23px;
  background: #377ba1;
  color: #717171;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e4e8;
}

.wrapper .main_content .info {
  margin: 20px;
  color: #717171;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.wrapper .main_content .info div {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#"><i class="fas"></i>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fas"></i>Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fas"></i>About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fas"></i>Blogs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fas"></i>Contacts</a></li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @Shining yes you should change the css. but since you have to ask, did you really make this yourself?